# Unable to import/export vuejs components

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a folder like this.

```
VueTree
  components
    Classic.vue
    Modern.vue
  index.js
```

Classic and Modern are simple components with `template`, `export default {}` and a `style`. 
I am calling both inside `index.js` as:

```
import Classic from './components/Classic.vue'
import Modern from './components/Modern.vue'

const VueTree= {
  Classic ,
  Modern 
}

export default VueTree
```

So, when I import this module as:

```
import {Classic , Modern } from '../../modules/VueTree/index.js'
```

I get this error

Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I have `name: "Classic"` inside my components and I am including the in the current file using `components: { Classic },` but I get the same error.

It only works if I export only one component as:

```
import Classic from './components/Classic.vue'
import Modern from './components/Modern.vue'
export default Classic
```

this will work and include the classic, but I can't export both of them like seen in this example https://github.com/greyby/vue-spinner/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `export` for named exports, not `export default`:

```
import Classic from './components/Classic.vue'
import Modern from './components/Modern.vue'

export {
  Classic ,
  Modern 
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Hmm.. I just changed it and I get the same error. `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Classic> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Setting>` Setting is the page that imports the components. The name is really there

Comment: That's strange, I've tested this in one of my projects and it works absolutely fine, I get the error you are receiving if I use `export default`. It may be a browser caching issue, try opening up your site in a `private window/incognito mode` and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Yup. Just tried it in incognito mode and the same error. Maybe it's the structure of my app `<template>
  <div>
 v classic
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: 'Classic',

 data () {
   return {

   }
 }
 
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>` Do you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: No, that looks fine. I've just noticed that there's a space between the file name and `.vue` it should be `'./components/Modern.vue'` not `'./components/Modern .vue'` so it might just be a typo? I'll change that in my answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry that was just a typo when pasting. I have eslint and I have no errors. Like I said, if I export only one it works perfectly.

Comment: Hey, I put a bounty on this can you check again what the issue is? thanks

Comment: @hidar I can't actually see anything wrong with what you are doing. I've added a working example on my [GitHub page](https://github.com/craigh411/export-example) which uses `webpack-simple` from the [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). All I've done is added the two components in [src/components](https://github.com/craigh411/export-example/tree/master/src/components) and created an [index.js](https://github.com/craigh411/export-example/blob/master/src/index.js) to export them. I've then imported them in to [App.vue](https://github.com/craigh411/export-example/blob/master/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2):

The setup you have is fine.

```
import Classic from './components/Classic.vue'
import Modern from './components/Modern.vue'

const VueTree = {
  Classic,
  Modern
}
export VueTree
```

The problem is your [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#ad). I can see you're using a [Treeview](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html) so, it is a [recursive component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Recursive-Components). You should be extra careful about how you create them because it can create a *infinite loop*.

Take a look at my *github* for a example on how your `VueTree` should work.

Ps: Don't forget to add a [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) and a name  to a *recursive component*.

> Components can recursively invoke themselves in their own template. However, they can only do so with the `name` option. *Vue Docs*.

*If what i said does not work. Feel free to send me a* github link *to the issue and i will be happy to help.*

Comment: I'm not using the vuetree as seen there. This is my own module, there is no recursive call. They are just two simple hello world files for now. Also, your const is missing = and export VueTree is throwing `Unexpected token, expected {` error

Comment: @hidar Was missing a equal sign. Check again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

### index.js

```
export { default as Classic } from './components/Classic.vue'
export { default as Modern } from './components/Modern.vue'
```

### Modern.vue

```
import { Classic } from './components/index';

export default {
   components: { Classic }
}
```

**NOTICE:** Chlidren component must by exported just BEFORE parent component in index.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do this

**index.js / index.ts**

```
import ParentName from './ParentName.vue'
import ChildName from './ChildName.vue'

export default ParentName

export { ChildName }
```

**ComponentName.vue**

```
import ParentName, { ChildName } from '~/components/abstractName'

export default {
   components: {
       ParentName,
       ChildName
   }
}
```